# Swift - Pass a reference to a class

Tags: swift2

I have a class which will perform a search. Once complete I want the search class to pass back the results to which ever instance (of another class) started the search. My thinking was to pass a reference to the class which instantiates the search class and use that reference to call a function. Here's a basic example of what I'm trying to do. How can I get this to work, or is there another/better way?

Search Class (I've tried AnyObject and UITableViewContoller):

```
class SearchClass : NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate, NSURLConnectionDataDelegate {
    var callingClass : AnyObject? = nil //To store reference to the "other" class
    var searchResults : [[String : AnyObject]]? = nil

    init(callingClass: AnyObject) { //I don't know the name of the ViewController class which will instantiates this as it will be called by several different classes
        self.callingClass = callingClass
    }

    func startSearch(searchString: String) {
        //NSURLConnection etc
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection) {
        //more code
        searchResults = ...
        callingClass!.searchCompleted(searchResults) //Pass the search results back to the class instance which started the search  
    }
}
```

Other Classes:

```
class RandomViewController : UITableViewController {

    //The casting on the next line fails
    let Searcher = SearchClass(callingClass: self as! UITableViewController) //OR AnyObject

    func randomFunction() {
        searcher.startSearch("search query")
    }

    func searchComplete(searchResults: [[String : AnyObject]]) {
        self.searchResults = searchResults
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a closure parameter to your `startSearch` function in your search class:

```
typealias SearchResultHandler = (result: [String : AnyObject]) -> ()

func startSearch(query: String, resultHandler: SearchResultHandler) {
    // send the search request and in the completion handler of the request call your result handler:
    resultHandler(result: searchResult)
}
```

Which you would then call from any class:

```
let searcher = SearchClass()
searcher.startSearch("query") { (result) -> () in
    self.searchResults = results
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: That works, thank you. It appears that the startSearch call will wait for the result to return. If for some reason the search took a while to complete would this cause the UI to hang?

Comment: Yes you should do the search asynchronously in the background and execute the closure on the main thread when the search is complete

Comment: Most frameworks offer a completionHandler when you send a request. So the request is already done asynchronously. All you have to do is call your `resultHandler` in the completionHandler of the request method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics when you don't know what the class is going to be:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html

**However....**

This seems like something that you should use protocol / delegates for.

```
// NOTE: weak references must be class type
protocol SearchClassDelegate: class {
    func searchComplete(results: [[String: AnyObject]?])
}

// This is where you define T as the generic class
class SearchClass {

    weak var delegate: SearchClassDelegate? // This is your "callingClass"
    // NOTE: make sure it's weak

    // ...

    func connectionDidFinishLoading() {
        // ...
        self.delegate?.searchComplete(results)
    }
}

// Set to the delegate
class ViewController: UIViewController, SearchClassDelegate {

    // ...
    // Make sure you set the delegate

    // Here is where you implement this function
    func searchComplete(results: [[String : AnyObject]?]) {
        // Do whatever
        // ...reloadData() etc.
    }

}
```